# Rooted Genymotion

Tags: root, genymotion

I use genymotion to emulate Google Nexus 9.I want to run an app which can be only run in rooted mode.So I want to know is there any way that genymotion can be rooted...is so how?
Thnx for any help.

Comment: where is genymotion running ? on your machine or on your smartphone ? rooting can be deadly to your machines, why do you put such questions ?

Comment: @dschinn1001 In what way is rooting deadly ? I have used many phones, all rooted, never had an issue.

Comment: @ratcoder - so where should it run in rooted mode ? on your desktop or on your android device ? ...

Comment: @dschinn1001-It should run on my desktop in rooted mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Genymotion VM's are rooted by default,on some Android LP roms, you must go to `settings` >> `Developer options` and `allow root access`.

Also `super user` or `super su` should be installed to confirm root.

[Related post on StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115571/root-genymotion-devices)

Comment: Although I can't find developer options...but "super su" confirmed it's running in rooted mode.Thnx for the help.

Comment: You must activate the options, go to settings >> about and press the build number 7 times, it will then be in the settings app. Its good to have as you can deny root to all apps but still allow ADB to use it.

Comment: There is no about in settings.....there is general, account, network, virtual box, ADB, misc tabs only in settings.

Comment: Sorry, not in Genymotion settings but Android settings app in your rom, says something like `about phone`.

Comment: After unlocking developers options you will get root, there is no **allow root access** option anymore